# Debye-Huckel limiting law

Tags: physical-chemistry

I encountered this equation when studying the Electrolyte solutions chapter in my analytical Chemistry textbook, Actually the terms in summation are giving a physical clue of what $I$ is, But what's the point of that $\frac{1}{2}$ ?
I've searched the Internet and a molecular Thermodynamics book that I have but I found nothing but the equation itself.

$I=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i}m_{i}z_{i}^{2}$

Comment: The ionic strength *I* has been *defined* in this way since 1921. It is just the molality of a 1:1 electrolyte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I$ is the [ionic strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_strength) of a solution, and is a measurement of the concentration of ions in a solution. $m_i$ is the concentration of the ion i, and $z_i$ is the charge of that ion. The $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the summation is a result of the fact that both positive and negative ions are considered when calculating the ionic strength. $m_i$ could either be a measurement of Molarity or molality, and your book should state which definition you are using (I assume molality due to the lowercase m).

Comment: $m$ is mass, $b$ is molal concentration (molality) and $c$ is molar concentration (molarity).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? We actually are considering both positive and negative Ions in $z^2$ term so the more of both or one of them results in a bigger ionic strength, Does this formula has a proof or It's just a model of prediction?

Comment: If I am correct, the ionic strength is an empirical result. The $\frac{1}{2}$ term is nice because it means that the ionic strength of a 1:1 electrolyte is equal to its concentration. Also, according to [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ed078p1691), m refers to the molality of the solution.

Comment: I prefer to use b for molality, but indeed m is also used. Also, I would add that it's better to formally divide each molality by standard molality of 1 mol/kg so that you end up with a dimensionless quantity.